# What is the correct API and node SDK to append rows to Excel in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, microsoft-graph, graph-api

I've been asked if I can change from appending row data from Google Sheets as I currently am, to "an Excel sheet in Sharepoint [online]".

Really very simple - "*date, time, event*" appended to whatever the next row is. I don't know *why* they want it in Excel like this, but having spent a large part of the weekend getting more confused, guidance and pointers would be appreciated before I disappear down too many more rabbit holes.

I have an Office 365 subscription but I am not familiar with Sharepoint and am having trouble figuring out the answer.

I see there is "[A new graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/new-graph-explorer-is-now-ga/)" just out this month (May 2020), but the [Microsoft Graph API client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client) package on npm was updated 7 months ago.

If there's no simple method I am happy to use some kind of bridge involving any combination of Flow, IFTTT, Zapier, MQTT - whatever works.

Footnote: With G sheets, I just bundle up the data and auth into an object, and then do this:

`await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(request)`

Just looking for the most fuss-free equivalent in Sharepoint / Excel online. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/~officedevpnp

Comment: Have a look at the above!

Comment: Well, thank you so much - what an obtuse and undescriptively named package! It doesn't appear in searches for pretty much anything anyone would be looking for. However, this confirms the answer that, no, it is not possible to write to Excel on any platform except Onedrive for Business, so we have to stick to G Sheets for now until the MS library matures and builds out new features. Thanks for helping me resolve this!  
    https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0
 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/excel-write-to-workbook